# How to split on first delimiter

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have an array of items I want to split on (this is for a page ).

I'm trying to 'intelligently' extract out a title, but only the relevant part.

I also dont want leading/trailing spaces.

I'm not quite sure how to go about doing this though.. without putting a bunch of loops inside of other loops.

```
function cleanTitle(title) {
    // Extract up to first delimiter
    var delims = ['|','·','-',':'];
}
```

I am using jquery.

I also put the delims array in order of what I feel is most important. Instead of searching the entire title for the first array item before moving on to the next, I think it should do the entire string one letter at a time... each letter of the string it will check if its contained within that array. If not, it moves on. I know a lot of urls might contain even 3 out of all 4 of these, and then it wouldnt really work well otherwise.

Comment: Can you post an example of how your array looks like and what the title should be based on your requirements? I can't picture your problem...

Comment: unfortunately, I think to do exactly what you want you'll have to write some custom functions with loops, but using the `split()` method you can do something similar with a regexp parameter as...`"my str".split(/(\||-|:|\.)/gi)`...you'll have to fool with the regexp

Comment: @andbeyond: I was thinking about that too, if OP posts example we can see if it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex to do the work for you:

```
var str = "This is a title-And the rest of the string";
var title;
var matchChar = str.match(/^(.*?)[|·\-:]/);
if (matchChar) {
    title = matchChar[1];   // "This is a title"
} else {
    title = str;
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/kxVMB/

Comment: God damnit thats so much easier than what I was doing> I have no idea why I didn't even think of that.

Comment: @Tallboy - make sure you look at my latest edits because I fixed a problem in the original version.

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm going to pretend I never even asked this retarded question.

Comment: Can you explain what this part means `^(.*?)` .. not 0 or mroe of any character?

Comment: @Tallboy - The `?` makes it a non-greedy wildcard match so that `.*` matches the fewest number of chars rather than the most chars.  This lets it stop on the first delimiter rather than that last delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

`split` accepts regex or a string as its param. You can make the solution a little less verbose:

```
function cleanTitle(title) {
    return title.split(/[-.|:]/)[0];
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/JkRv6/

Comment: What if there is no delimiter in the string?

Comment: You just thought of that in your answer 52 seconds ago too hahah. Added the failsave.

Comment: Not exactly.  My answer already had an `if` statement for whether a match was there and it was up to the OP to decide what to do if no delimiter.

Comment: Here's something funny.  Your original answer actually works when no delimiter and you don't need the changes you added: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/qz7EG/

Comment: No, in mine I always had `if (match)` and it was up to the OP to decide what to do if there was no match as they didn't specify the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

All of these answers ***ignore*** the obvious and most elegant solution (although RegEx is certainly an improvement over a loop).  Just use `string.split(/^(.*?)[|·\-:]/,1)`  This is *ECMAScript 1* so I don't see why it wouldn't be available in all browsers.

## Syntax

`string.split(separator, limit)`

---

## Parameters

#### Parameter   Description

`separator                  Optional. Specifies the character, or the regular 
                            expression, to use for splitting the string. If 
                            omitted, the entire string will be returned (an 
                            array with only one item)`

`limit                      Optional. An integer that specifies the number of 
                            splits, items after the split limit will not be 
                            included in the array`